# regex for soundcloud social media profiles/urls

Tags: regex

I´m looking to extract the FACEBOOK or other social media profiles URLS form the site SOUNDCLOUD.

example url:
https://soundcloud.com/netztherapie

There is the link to that profiles social media profile.
When using regular expressions for facebook it doesn't catch it.

I wonder what a adequate regex for this code would be:

CODE:

```
a href="https://exit.sc?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FNetztherapie-641177919313762%2F" target="_blank" rel="me nofollow" class="web-profile sc-link-light sc-social-logo-interactive">
  <span class="sc-social-logo sc-social-logo-facebook"></span>
  Wir auf Facebook!
</a
```

I'm looking to extract:

```
https://www.facebook.com/Netztherapie/
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines is what you'll probably want to do:

```
regex = "www\.facebook\.com%2F([^-]+)-"
```

You probably don't actually have to capture the www.facebook.com or https:// because you know that.  Easier to just try and grab the name and then make the string.  Here is an easy to read (although the string concatenation is not proper Python) example:

```
import re

regex = "www\.facebook\.com%2F([^-]+)-"

match = re.search(regex, """a href="https://exit.sc?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FNetztherapie-641177919313762%2F" target="_blank" rel="me nofollow" class="web-profile sc-link-light sc-social-logo-interactive"> Wir auf Facebook!""")
if match:
    print ("yep")
    thename = match.group(1)
    print ("https://www.facebook.com/" + thename + "/")

else:
    print ("nope")
```

The regex is just grabbing all non - after the base URL.  That should at least get you headed in the right direction.  You probably need to tweak the regex after you run some tests, maybe you don't want the www. in there for example, I'm not sure how uniform all the soundcloud URLs really are.